# Flutter bloc rebuild on change state

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

For filter my list I use a state FilterState.
I have in this state my list filter but my widget for build list is not rebuild.
My print shows that the list is correct according to the state.
But `GameList` keeps its initial state which is not filtered : it's not rebuild.

Thanks,

*my page for state :*

```
            BlocBuilder<GameBloc, GameState>(
                builder: (context, state) {
                  if (state is LoadingState) {
                    return buildLoading();
                  } else if (state is FailState) {
                    return ErrorUI(message: state.message);
                  } else if (state is ListLoadedState) {
                    _list = state.list;
                    return GameList(list: state.list!);
                  } else if (state is FilterGamesState) {
                    print(state.list);
                    return GameList(list: state.list!);
                  }
                  return Container();
                },
              ),
```

*Bloc Page :*

```
class GameBloc extends Bloc<GameEvent, GameState> {
  GameBloc({required this.repository}) : super(LoadingState()) {
    on<BackEvent>(_onBackEvent);
    on<FetchGamesEvent>(_onFetchList);
    on<FetchGameEvent>(_onFetchItem);
    on<SavingEvent>(_onSavingEvent);
    on<UpdateGameEvent>(_onUpdate);
    on<CreateGameEvent>(_onCreate);
    on<FilterGamesEvent>(_onFilter);
  }

  GameRepository repository;
  final currentFilter = BehaviorSubject<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  Future<void> _onFilter(
    FilterGamesEvent event,
    Emitter<GameState> emit,
  ) async {
    try {
      emit(LoadingState());
      final list = event.list?.where((Game item) {
        if (currentFilter.value.containsKey('player')) {
          int players = currentFilter.value['player'].nb;
          return players.isBetween(from: item.nopMin, to: item.nopMax);
        }
        return true;
      }).where((Game item) {
        if (currentFilter.value.containsKey('age')) {
          return item.age!.isBetween(
              from: currentFilter.value['age'].min,
              to: currentFilter.value['age'].max);
        }
        return true;
      }).where((Game item) {
        if (currentFilter.value.containsKey('duration')) {
          return compareToDuration(
              item.durMin!,
              item.durMax!,
              currentFilter.value['duration'].min,
              currentFilter.value['duration'].max);
        }
        return true;
      }).where((Game item) {
        if (currentFilter.value.containsKey('tags')) {
          return item.tags!
              .compareToList(currentFilter.value['tags'] as List<String>);
        }
        return true;
      }).where((Game item) {
        if (currentFilter.value.containsKey('collection')) {
          return item.collection!
              .compareToList(currentFilter.value['collection'] as List<String>);
        }
        return true;
      }).toList();
      emit(FilterGamesState(listGame: list!));
    } catch (e) {
      emit(const FailState(message: 'Failed to fetch all games data.'));
    }
  }
```

*Event Page :*

```
abstract class GameEvent extends Equatable {
  final Game? item;
  const GameEvent({this.item});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class InitialEvent extends GameEvent {
  const InitialEvent({required Game item}) : super(item: item);
}

class BackEvent extends GameEvent {}

class SavingEvent extends GameEvent {}

class FetchGameEvent extends GameEvent {
  const FetchGameEvent({required Game item}) : super(item: item);
}

class FetchGamesEvent extends GameEvent {}

class FilterGamesEvent extends GameEvent {
  const FilterGamesEvent({required this.list});
  final List<Game>? list;
}
```

*State Page :*

```
abstract class GameState extends Equatable {
  final Game? item;
  final List<Game>? list;
  const GameState({this.item, this.list});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class GameInitial extends GameState {}

class FailState extends GameState {
  const FailState({required this.message});
  final String message;
}

class LoadingState extends GameState {}

class ListLoadedState extends GameState {
  const ListLoadedState({required this.listGame}) : super(list: listGame);
  final List<Game> listGame;
}

class ItemLoadedState extends GameState {
  const ItemLoadedState({required this.game}) : super(item: game);
  final Game game;
}

class FilterGamesState extends GameState {
  const FilterGamesState({required this.listGame}) : super(list: listGame);
  final List<Game> listGame;
}
```

Comment: can you show your bloc.dart , event.dart and state.dart file ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this,

I send the key to GameList in FilterGameState.

```
else if (state is FilterGamesState) {
    print(state.list);
    return GameList(key: GlobalKey<GameFilterState>(), list: state.list!);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Equatable but your props are empty. If you're using Equatable make sure to pass all properties to the props getter. (In both your state and event!)

Source: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/faqs?id=state-not-updating

The [Flutter Todos Tutorial](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttertodostutorial) might also be helpful because it uses a filter too.